# Laravel one to many parent / child relationship on the same model

Tags: laravel

i have one to many relation on the same model and the same table

table has fields (id , name , parent_id)

and my Specialization Model has these code :

```
 public function mainSpecialization()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Specialization::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function subSpecializations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Specialization::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

and i wrote these function to get all sub specialization :

```
public function subSpecialization()
{
    return $this->model->where('parent_id', '!=', null)->get();
}
```

i get collection of specialization but without the parent
how to get the parent

Comment: try this return $this->model->where('parent_id', '!=', null)->with('Specialization')->get();
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive relationship :

```php
    public function subSpecializations()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Specialization::class);
    }

    public function subSpecializationRecursive()
    {
        return $this->subSpecializations()
                     ->with('subSpecializationRecursive');
    }
```